# iterative solution to permutation calculation in C

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, iteration, permutation

I'm working on a problem dealing with iteration. I'm supposed to pass in two ints into a function, which represent a number of N objects and M values that I must find all permutations of. I am also given a sample of what the output is supposed to look like

void perm_iter(int N, int nr_values)
and the output this is supposed to print is :

```
Called : perm_iter(3, 2);

0  0  0
0  0  1
0  1  0
0  1  1
1  0  0
1  0  1
1  1  0
1  1  1
```

I understand the concept of recursion by using a swap function to change the orders of strings to find all permutations of a string, but I'm unsure of how to use iteration to get the same, or similar result. Is this a case where I need to use the stack and push/pop iteratively to get my answer? I was thinking I could use something like a set of nested loops to take the place of recursion and get something like this output but I'm unsure how to set the loops up to go through every permutation and not just iterate, missing some of the possible permutations.

Any help would be appreciated, and thank you for your time.

Comment: Those aren't permutations, they are all strings of length 3 you can form with 2 symbols. Quite a different beast. Please clarify what you want.

Comment: This is essentially an incrementing odometer, with n digits base m.

Comment: The parameter, `N = 3`, seems represented in your example by having three digits on each line. Could you please explain how the parameter, `nr_values = 2`, features in your example? I thought maybe the number of `1`s or `0`ss might be fixed to 2 but that does not seem to be the case. What does `nr_values` correspond with in the example?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to count up each "digit" until the max is reached, then reset and increment the next.

Imagine nr_values is 10 (with n=2):

```
0 0
0 1 
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
0 6
0 7
0 8
0 9 
1 0
1 1 
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
1 7
1 8
1 9
```

Looks familiar because it's just "regular" counting in this case.

Implement this just like you count up: In each step, increment the leftmost value. If max is reached, reset and increment the next value etc.

```
void perm_iter(int n, int nr_values) {
  int[] counter = new int[n];
  int i;

  // Clear all values
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    counter[i] = 0;
  }

  do {
    // Print the current set of values
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      printf("%n ", counter[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Keep incrementing while the values overflow,
    // starting at the rightmost counter
    i = n - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
      counter[i]++;
      if (counter[i] < nr_values) {
        break;
      } 
      counter[i] = 0;
      i--;
    }
    // We are done when the first value overflows
  } while (i >= 0);
}
```

Comment: You are forming all possible `n` strings out of `nr_values`, which is what the question shows, not permutations, what the question states.

Comment: One option to get the permutations only would be to do an additonal scan whether the value is in the array already -- and to skip it, if so.